# as3 trying to make mc visiable when go to previous frame

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

now
in frame 1 i have 5 buttons everyone go to spcific frame
and everybutton has a mc
the idea is when the user click on button 1 ( as example ) it will go to frame 2 ( in frame 2 i have a video with fuction when its finished it will go to the frame 1 and make the mc of button 1 alpha is 1
so the other button same idea
the proplem is i need all the buttons user cliked and went to the frame and go back i need the mc of this buttons to be visiable but what realy happen its the only button i clicked and went back mc of it is visiable and when click other buttons and go back the mc of the button showed but the previuos clicked button mc of it its not
this is the code of the button

```
    gotoAndStop(22);
```

this is the function of video complete to back

```
gam_mc.gamvid.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, videoComplete2);

 function videoComplete2(event:Event):void //event:Event not event:VideoEvent
 {
     gam_mc.gamvid.pause();
bt1_mc.alpha = 1;
    gotoAndStop(20);
 }
```

the bt1_mc is the mc of button 1 on the frame 1

now i need a way to make every mc of clicked button to be showed so the user now what button he clicked and what not

Comment: You need a persistent (not vanishing) data structure that holds the history of clicked buttons and then use it every time you go to the frame 1 to hide those buttons you have already tried.

Comment: i don't understand this "You need a persistent (not vanishing) data structure  "  ? u mean make all the button work on same frame ?

Comment: "Persistent" means data, that keeps its last assigned value, does not reset to default value, and remains accessible with no regard to any activity that is not directly addressed at it. Imagine a **Boolean** variable **firstButtonWasPressed** which is initially **false**, then becomes **true** upon pressing the first button, and every time you are back to frame 1 you check it and hide the first button if the variable is **true**.

Comment: if the Boolean was false in frame 1 then become true when button pressed .. every time back to frame 1 will back to false and witll not solve the matter >>   right ?

Comment: That exactly what the "persistent" part is for.